# Strict mode and reserved word

Tags: javascript, strict-mode

Why is this code fine:

```
var test = {
    fn1: function(_origin, _componentType) {
        if(arguments.length > 1) throw "xx";
        // this strict is ok
        "use strict";

        var interface               = new Object(this);
    }
}
```

While this isn't

```
var test = {
    fn1: function(_origin, _componentType) {
        // This strict throws SyntaxError
        "use strict";

        if(arguments.length > 1) throw "xx";
        var interface               = new Object(this);
    }
}
```

I know interface is reserved word in strict mode, but shouldn't both examples throw an error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`"use strict";` needs to be the first statement in a function (or in a script, if script-wide) to trigger strict mode; anywhere else, you may as well be writing `"merry christmas";`.

Comment: _+1_ for `"merry christmas";`

Answer (score 4):

The first example doesn't actually enable strict mode. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Invoking_strict_mode:

> Strict mode applies to *entire scripts* or to *individual functions*. It doesn't apply to block statements enclosed in {} braces; attempting to apply it to such contexts does nothing.

Comment: I'm sure this works as you describe, but it seems like a pretty brittle convention, prone to confusion like the OP's.  Is there any explanation of why they did it like this?

Comment: @chicks Sorry, I don't know. It was obviously inspired by Perl's `use strict`, but that does work anywhere. Maybe it's easier to implement this way?

Comment: Yet the Perl version allows you to `no strict` and `use strict` in the middle of things.  Too bad people that steal from Perl steal only steal half of a feature. :)

Comment: @chicks: In Perl, `use strict` is a statement. In JavaScript, to avoid backward breakage, it is just a string, that is given special treatment. I am purely guessing here, but with the restriction, the parser needs to only check the first statement for special status. It also makes sure that programmers understand that it affects the *whole function*, not just the bit after it; for example, `function(x, x) { "use strict"; return x; }` does throw an error in JS even though the erroneous bit is technically before it; in Perl, `$foo = "foo"; use strict;` does not throw an error.